# How can I append a hashtag to local html file URL obtained with fileURLWithPath?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am trying to build a URL string that will be passed to UIWebView object. Up until now I have been pointing to remote files and have now moved the files into the main bundle. 
I imported my files using the "create folder reference" option and want to point to the index.html file inside of a folder named 'html'.

I need to append hashtags to the URL generated by the code below but keep getting this error:

**-[NSURL stringByAppendingString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

I can't figure out why when casting my variables as a NSString I am receiving this error when trying to append to it.

Here is my code:

```c
NSInteger rowNumber = indexPath.row;
NSInteger metroRank = rowNumber+1; //sorted by rank, adding one because of zero-based array


NSString *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"html"]];
NSString *urlSuffix = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"#pg=metro&view=%d", metroRank];
NSString *metroViewURL = [url stringByAppendingString:urlSuffix];
```

When the above code hits 'stringByAppendString' that is when I receive the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a NSString first:

```
NSString *newURL = [[oldURL absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:@"#myhashtag"];
```

Comment: Richard - This put me on the right path. I changed my url variable to be a NSURL instead of NSString and then referenced it like this: 

NSString *metroViewURL = [[url absoluteString] stringByAppendingString:urlSuffix];

Comment: @DustinCarpenter ah, right, I forgot that you have to manually create a NSURL from it first.

Answer (score 1):

[NSURL fileURLWithPath:] does not return a NSString, but a NSURL. NSURL does not implement the  stringByAppendingString selector. You can use URLByAppendingPathComponent: instead.

Comment: skidr0w - +1 for the additional info, it was also useful.